# Display image when mouseover on Text in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice

Can any one please help me on how to display an image when mouseover on text in LibreOffice impress.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is possible by adding a [mouse listener](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/GUI/Events).

However it is much easier to right-click on the text, choose `Interaction` and select one of the options for `Action at mouse click`.  This will require the user to click on the text.

For mouseover functionality, it is better to create HTML files instead of using LibreOffice.  For example, see http://www.kevinandamanda.com/javascript-tutorial-mouseover-an-image-thumbnail-to-get-a-pop-up-preview/.

See also https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=9487 for discussion about Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I managed with adding the hyper links to the images when clicked.